# Update Google fusion tables dynamically using MySQL or other databases

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have read
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/developers_guide#Writ...
to get an idea but i would like to know if there is a full tutorial to show how
to dynamically update the fusion table with data stored on MYSQL database
or other type of databases? something very simple like a working example

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any tutorial's but there are quite a few examples in various programming languages. E.g. I used the python library to get my data stored in Postgres into Fusion Tables. Basically created a CSV dump of my database and used the python client to insert/update my Fusion Table.

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/sample_code